# Print the Nth record before some regexp with awk

Tags: awk

I have the awk command which is finding *"match"* and adding  *"string"* 5 lines after it:

```
awk '1;/match/{c=5}c&&!--c{print "string"}'
```

How to modify it to add *"string"* N lines, but **BEFORE** the *"match"*?

For example, i have a test.txt file:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

using my command I can have:

```
cat test.txt | awk '1;/six/{c=2}c&&!--c{print "addedstring"}'
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
addedstring
eight
nine
ten
```

so I need to modify my command to add *addedstring* 2 lines BEFORE *six*:

```
one
two
three
four
addedstring
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for showing your efforts in your question. Could you please post samples of input and expected output too in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, thanks, I have added an example

Comment: @mikrupin: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Do a `tac`+ `awk`+`tac` combination and it will be done easily. Using OP's attempted awk code here itself.

```
tac Input_file | awk '1;/six/{c=2}c&&!--c{print "addedstring"}' | tac
```

***Explanation:*** using `tac` command which will simply print all contents in reverse order. So by doing this `six` comes in reverse order and line gets added after 1 line of it, but wait this is a reverse order NOT actual Input_file order so again we pass its output to `tac` to do a reverse printing on already done reverse printing(by first tac), by this way contents will come in their original form and newly added line will also be moved above(since it was added after `six` but in reverse order).

Sample output will be as follows.

```
one
two
three
four
addedstring
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

Answer (score 0):

This require to process the input file twice without using other tools.

```
awk -v lb=2 '
    /six/ && !found   { lb=FNR-lb+1; found=1; nextfile }
    NR != FNR && found{ print (FNR==lb?"addedstring" ORS $0: $0) }' infile infile
```

Or with GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v lb=2 '
    /six/ && !found{ lb=FNR-lb+1; found=1; nextfile }
              found{ print (FNR==lb?"addstring" ORS $0: $0) }' infile infile
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, this can be done easily using command line `vim`:

```sh
vim -e - file -c '/^six$/' -c 'norm kOaddedstring' -c 'wq'
```

or a more readable version:

```sh
vim -e - file <<EOF
/^six$/
norm kOaddedstring
wq
EOF
```

Then check file content:

```sh
cat file

one
two
three
four
addedstring
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

**vim command explanation:**

- `/^six$/`: Match a line with only `six` as content
- `norm kOaddedstring`: Enter `normal` command mode. `k` moves a line up and `O` inserts text `addedstring` before current line
- `wq`: Save and quit changes